# How do I count the roles of group members in Moodle 3.5 courses in pure SQL?

Tags: mysql, moodle

I'm trying to write a MySQL report on the Moodle 3.5 database to return a list of courses, some enrolment details, course's groups (if any), and count the members in these groups if they are enrolled as certain roles. My query displays the category, course, and groupname columns correctly (`null` is intentional here), but the `groupstudentcount` and `groupspnetcount` columns are incorrect in some rows. Can you see where I've gone wrong?

Intended Results:

```
| category                   | course               | group                       | groupmembertotal | groupstudentcount | groupspnetcount |
|----------------------------|----------------------|-----------------------------|------------------|-------------------|-----------------|
| Commercial Cookery         | Baking               | NULL                        | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Commercial Cookery         | Cookies              | Newcastle                   | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Commercial Cookery         | Cookies              | Ultimo                      | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Miscellaneous              | Dummy Course         | NULL                        | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Miscellaneous              | TDC Unit No Students | Course template_2018 course | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Miscellaneous              | TDC Unit No Students | Group 1                     | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Miscellaneous Sub-category | Apples               | Newcastle                   | 1                | 0                 | 1               |
| Miscellaneous Sub-category | Apples               | Ultimo                      | 2                | 2                 | 0               |
| Miscellaneous Sub-category | Test course          | Newcastle                   | 2                | 1                 | 1               |
| Miscellaneous Sub-category | Test course          | Ultimo                      | 1                | 1                 | 0               |
| TDC                        | TDC Course Template  | NULL                        | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| TDC                        | TDC Unit Tempate     | Course template_2018 course | 1                | 0                 | 1               |
| TDC                        | TDC Unit Tempate     | Group 1                     | 1                | 1                 | 0               |
```

Actual Results:

```
| category                   | course               | group                       | groupmembertotal | groupstudentcount | groupspnetcount |
|----------------------------|----------------------|-----------------------------|------------------|-------------------|-----------------|
| Commercial Cookery         | Baking               | NULL                        | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Commercial Cookery         | Cookies              | Newcastle                   | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Commercial Cookery         | Cookies              | Ultimo                      | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Miscellaneous              | Dummy Course         | NULL                        | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Miscellaneous              | TDC Unit No Students | Course template_2018 course | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Miscellaneous              | TDC Unit No Students | Group 1                     | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| Miscellaneous Sub-category | Apples               | Newcastle                   | 1                | 0                 | 1               |
| Miscellaneous Sub-category | Apples               | Ultimo                      | 2                | 2                 | 0               |
| Miscellaneous Sub-category | Test course          | Newcastle                   | 2                | 0 (should = 1)    | 2  (should = 1) |
| Miscellaneous Sub-category | Test course          | Ultimo                      | 1                | 1                 | 0               |
| TDC                        | TDC Course Template  | NULL                        | 0                | 0                 | 0               |
| TDC                        | TDC Unit Tempate     | Course template_2018 course | 1                | 0                 | 1               |
| TDC                        | TDC Unit Tempate     | Group 1                     | 1                | 1                 | 0               |
```

Data tables:
mdl_course_categories cat

```
| id | name                       |
|----|----------------------------|
| 1  | Miscellaneous              |
| 2  | TDC                        |
| 3  | Miscellaneous Sub-category |
| 4  | Test                       |
| 5  | Course Offerings           |
| 6  | Commerical Cookery         |
```

mdl_course c

```
| id | category | fullname              |
|----|----------|-----------------------|
| 1  | 0        | Localhost Moodle v3.5 |
| 2  | 2        | TDC Unit Tempate      |
| 3  | 2        | TDC Course Template   |
| 4  | 1        | Dummy Course          |
| 5  | 1        | TDC Unit No Students  |
| 6  | 6        | Baking                |
| 7  | 6        | Cookies               |
| 8  | 3        | Apples                |
| 9  | 3        | Test course           |
```

mdl_groups g

```
| id | courseid | name                        |
|----|----------|-----------------------------|
| 1  | 2        | Group 1                     |
| 2  | 2        | Course template_2018 course |
| 3  | 5        | Group 1                     |
| 4  | 5        | Course template_2018 course |
| 5  | 7        | Newcastle                   |
| 6  | 7        | Ultimo                      |
| 7  | 9        | Newcastle                   |
| 8  | 9        | Ultimo                      |
| 9  | 8        | Newcastle                   |
| 10 | 8        | Ultimo                      |
```

mdl_groups_members gm

```
| id | groupid | userid |
|----|---------|--------|
| 1  | 2       | 2      |
| 3  | 1       | 4      |
| 4  | 7       | 3      |
| 5  | 8       | 4      |
| 6  | 7       | 2      |
| 7  | 9       | 2      |
| 8  | 10      | 4      |
| 9  | 10      | 3      |
```

mdl_context ct where contextlevel = 50 (50 is the course context, where these enrollments I'm reporting on occur as per the [documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Roles#Context))

```
| id  | contextlevel | instanceid |
|-----|--------------|------------|
| 2   | 50           | 1          |
| 24  | 50           | 2          |
| 48  | 50           | 3          |
| 63  | 50           | 4          |
| 85  | 50           | 5          |
| 113 | 50           | 6          |
| 114 | 50           | 7          |
| 115 | 50           | 8          |
| 116 | 50           | 9          |
```

mdl_role_assignments ra

```
| id | roleid | contextid | userid |
|----|--------|-----------|--------|
| 1  | 5      | 24        | 3      |
| 2  | 5      | 48        | 3      |
| 3  | 5      | 24        | 4      |
| 4  | 5      | 48        | 4      |
| 5  | 5      | 24        | 2      |
| 6  | 9      | 116       | 2      |
| 7  | 5      | 116       | 3      |
| 8  | 5      | 116       | 4      |
| 11 | 5      | 115       | 4      |
| 12 | 9      | 115       | 2      |
| 13 | 9      | 113       | 2      |
| 15 | 5      | 115       | 3      |
```

Here's my query so far:

```sql
/* edit: re-wrote the query slightly differently than the original posted, and it removes some errors, but not all. I've updated the tables above with the required information. Old query here: https://pastebin.com/qBfh7kqV */

select
   cat.name category,
   c.fullname course,
   g.name groupname,
   count(distinct gm.userid) groupmembercount,
   case when ra.roleid = 5
      then count(distinct ra.userid)
      else 0
   end as groupstudentcount,
   case when ra.roleid = 9
      then count(distinct ra.userid)
      else 0
   end as groupspnetcount
from  mdl_course_categories cat
   join mdl_course c on cat.id = c.category
   join mdl_context ct on c.id = ct.instanceid
   and ct.contextlevel = 50
   left join mdl_groups g on ct.instanceid = g.courseid
   and ct.contextlevel = 50
   left join mdl_groups_members gm on g.id = gm.groupid
   left join mdl_role_assignments ra on gm.userid = ra.userid
group by
   cat.id,
   c.id,
   g.id
order by
   cat.name asc,
   c.fullname asc,
   g.name asc
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have like a start example of code?

Comment: @MihailMinkov whoops! I forgot to add it before posting. Please see my original post now.

Comment: I don't understand - why all the downvotes? It's a genuine request for assistance that meets the guidelines.

Comment: @Zectzodza it was because you failed to show any attempt whatsoever to do something. You must include at least what you attempted to do and explain where you got stuck and what happened.

Comment: Ah, so they were downvoting before I corrected my mistake. Fair enough.

Comment: I've updated my original content to include my query thus far and the required information from the tables to complete them. It returns one row that is incorrect, which I've highlighted in the 'actual results' table.

Comment: You query, your sample data and the actual output is not in SYNC. Your query is giving error. [CHECK HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f731d9e75c77bf41cd4942c1afe1897). Update the details accordingly.

Comment: my apologies @ArunPalanisamy - the mdl_course.name column should read mdl_course.fullname instead. I've updated the mdl_course table to include the `category` column too.

Comment: Still there are errors in your code. [CHECK HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f25cabbca5535a8e79ada9956e262763) Can you make it as a working fiddle ? There seems to be lot of issues For e.g, column in `select` that are not in `group by`. Even i tried by modifying ur query to get your actual output but failed to understand your logic. So if you can change the fiddle to give your actual output i can help you to get the expected output @Zectzozda

Answer (score 1):

I think the join on the context is wrong. The `mdl_groups` table has a `courseid`, so you should use that to join to `mdl_course`.

The `mdl_role_assignments` table has a `contextid`, so this is the one that needs the context join. So your join would look like

```
FROM mdl_course_categories cat
JOIN mdl_course c ON cat.id = c.category
JOIN mdl_context ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid AND ctx.contextlevel = 50
LEFT JOIN mdl_groups g ON g.courseid = c.id
LEFT JOIN mdl_groups_members gm ON g.id = gm.groupid
LEFT JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON gm.userid = ra.userid AND ra.contextid = ctx.id
```

Comment: Hi Russell, oddly enough, this was the join I used in my first iteration of this query, but it still renders the same (incorrect) data :( [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb1db3eb3f576ca082339521f32c3b3a) is the dbfiddle with your join.

Comment: Ah-ha! If i remove the `left join`s (ie, dont look at courses without groups or groups with 0 members), this works. If i leave the joins in, it breaks the counts in each `...count` column. I'll update my OP to this problem, as they now count correctly :D

Comment: Or should I leave this question and create another one so your comment remains in a valid context?

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b76df8cd50feb66a38c8f684d397457b) 

[dbfiddle left joins](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b433005ced08019704d890cd891bff17) links for my last comment.